# How to compile Sharp js for AWS Lambda with Docker

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, docker, npm, sharp

I believe I need to build some binaries of a javascript image library (sharp js) and I have a docker command from the sharp js docs but it doesn't seem to be working properly

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x npm install sharp
```

[Source](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#aws-lambda)

I'm running this on win10. I just know docker basics btw. I get good output from npm but I don't see the libs anywhere.

```
$ docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x npm install sharp

> sharp@0.25.2 install /var/task/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.9.1/libvips-8.9.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/package.json'
npm WARN task No description
npm WARN task No repository field.
npm WARN task No README data
npm WARN task No license field.

+ sharp@0.25.2
added 76 packages from 154 contributors and audited 163 packages in 10.221s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

This command keeps creating a directory called 'imageProcessing;C' that is empty. Alternatively is there a way I could just copy the libs found in the git repo into my node_modules folder somehow?

I'm trying to deploy the libs to Lambda using the serverless framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "$PWD", typing in the full path in quotes worked:

```
docker run -v "//z/Dropbox/WD/Other Sites/ImageLambdas/imageProcessing":/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x npm install sharp
```

Also I found a *Double Slash* is required to start the host path